# Linking with Apache Portable Runtime on MS Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, python-extensions, apr

I'm trying to build a Python extension which links to APR.  And this time it's on MS Windows...  (It works on Linux).

Here's where the build fails, the command, and the output formatted for readability:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe
    /nologo
    /INCREMENTAL:NO
    /LTCG
    /DLL
    /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2
    /MANIFESTUAC:NO
    /LIBPATH:c:\dev\protopy\lib/apr
    /LIBPATH:c:\bin\python\Libs
    /LIBPATH:c:\dev\protopy\.venv\libs
    /LIBPATH:c:\dev\protopy\.venv\PCbuild\amd64
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64"
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64"
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64"
    apr-1.lib
    /EXPORT:PyInit_wrapped build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/descriptors.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/binparser.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/defparser.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/protopy.lex.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/protopy.tab.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/pyhelpers.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib/list.obj
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/wrapper.obj
    /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\protopy\wrapped.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
    /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib\wrapped.cp36-win_amd64.lib

wrapper.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_wrapped' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib\wrapped.cp36-win_amd64.lib \
   and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\protopy/lib\wrapped.cp36-win_amd64.exp
descriptors.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol \
    __imp_apr_hash_set
```

(it actually misses all symbols I've used, not just this one).

I've built the `apr-1.lib` by running `nmake -f Makefile.win` in APR's top-level directory before, and this is how I produced `libapr-1.lib`.  Then I renamed to `apr-1.lib` it and put it in `c:\dev\protopy\lib/apr`, so the linker is actually able to find it, but it cannot find the required symbols...

## Question 1

How can I see what symbols are in the library?  (Maybe I compiled something wrong?)

---

OK, I found `dumpbin.exe`, but now I see that the symbol in the `apr-1.lib` is called `__imp__apr_hash_set` (notice the second double underscore), but the linker looks for `__imp_apr_hash_set` (single underscore).  What gives?  They were compiled with the same compiler / linker...

## Question 2

Is there anything specific to building Python extensions on MS Windows that makes it work in this way?  (I only tried this once in my life, and couldn't get it to work, but for different reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to APR project document

> choose either aprutil or libaprutil (for static or dynamic libraries)

means `apr-1.lib-->static` and `libapr-1.lib -->dynamic`  and

> To target the static .lib versions of the library, the consuming compiliation must define the macros APR_DECLARE_STATIC and APU_DECLARE_STATIC. This prevents the apr and apr-util symbols from being tagged as __declspec(dllimport), eliminating compiliation warnings and speeding up execution.

Comment: A little too late (I figured how to do this a while ago and completely forgotten I've even asked this question on SO), and I'm not even working on the project anymore :) but still interesting (I don't think I defined those macros).

Comment: I guess so, but felt forced to write for future users :) @wvxvw. Thank you for marking as answer.